# Timezone support with date-fns

Tags: timezone, momentjs, date-fns

I'm considering migrating my project using `moment` into `date-fns` which is known as simple, functional etc. But after I played with it a while, I noticed they don't support `timezone` yet. They have introduced `locale` and `timezone` option in `format` and other functionality in alpha 2.0.0 lately but the `locale` option is just a language support and the `timezone` option in those functions just shows/adds the `GMT` sign(ex. 2018.08.29 GMT+9). So I was wondering if I'm just missing it although they already support it or they really haven't supported it yet.

Comment: See https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/180.  In the meantime, you might want to consider [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352711/623816) a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45685066/623816) to this one. The time zone support should be added after date-fns 2.0 is released.

Answer (score 7):

There is [date-fns-timezone](https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone) which works with date-fns v1, and [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) for date-fns v2.

See the official [timezone documentation](https://date-fns.org/docs/Time-Zones#date-fns-tz) from date-fns, that points to date-fns-tz

Answer (score 0):

date-fns timezone support can be found here: https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone